# Nest 12084 ERROR Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated value s

Tags: typescript, nestjs, telegraf.js

i have a task. creating the telegram bot for pizzeria. i create couple of sheets in database database and getting this error **[Nest] 12084  - 05/01/2023, 9:06:18 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated value
s.**

what is i doing wrong?

https://pastebin.com/t6zDf2T0
my code

i have a task. creating the telegram bot for pizzeria. i create couple of sheets in database database and getting this error **[Nest] 12084  - 05/01/2023, 9:06:18 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated value
s.**. I write that question to chatgpt and he say what me need type this on App.update or app.service.ts, i try the answer? but those answer do not work for me.

help me please, guys

```
createQueryBuilder()
  .update(OrderItem)
  .set({ quantity: newQuantity })
  .where("id = :id", { id: orderId })
  .execute();
```

those code chatgpt will be recommend me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.